# Integrating IronScheme into Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, scheme, visual-studio-2012, ironscheme

Is there a way (or can anyone find a way) to import [IronScheme](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/) into VS2010? I've already taken a look at this question, and I've done everything I could - I even edited the binary files involved to change the version numbers.  My question: **Does anyone have a solution for getting IronScheme installed into VisualStudio 2010? at present, following [the directions to install it into VS2008](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IronScheme%20Visual%20Studio%202008%20Integration&referringTitle=Documentation) does not work for VS2010. Thanks in advance :)**

*Update 1*: I suppose I should post the error I get when I try to follow the directions for installing it via commandline:

```
C:\Program Files\IronScheme>RegPkg.exe /codebase "C:\Program Files\IronScheme\IronScheme.VisualStudio.dll"
```

After I run that, I get a Windows 7 popup error:

> RegPkg.exe Has Stopped Working - Windows is checking for a solution to
>   the problem...

When I click out of that, it gives me this error on the console:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.9.0, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.9.0, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.RegPkg.Main(String[] arguments)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: I have made one now :) See edited answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote the VS2008 plugin.

When VS2010, the whole API changed again, and if you have ever been in the VS SDK API, you will know it is a maze. I just did not feel like the effort again.

I have a bunch of great ideas but for the life of me I cannot even figure the simple stuff out.

If someone want to actually port my code from VS2008, I would appreciate it. It should not be too hard if you are a bit more familiar with the API than I am.

The source code for the VS2008 plugin is not currently available for the public. Please let me know if anyone is serious about so I can create a github (or similar) repo for it.

**Update:**

Created a [github repo](https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme.VisualStudio). The code is not the same as the existing DLL I distribute; it contains various half working ideas I was trying.

**Update 2:**

[Here](http://ironscheme.net/IronScheme.VisualStudio.rar) you go :) Very basic, but works on VS2010 and VS11 (should work on Express versions too). Source is in the `vs11` branch of above mentioned github repo. It is just a subset of what the VS2008 plugin does as some features seem to be broken or have broken due to bit rot.

**Update 3:**

<strike>Seems the VS2010 plugin fails if only VS2010 is installed. Will have to investigate. Works fine if both VS2010 and VS11 is installed.</strike> FIXED :)

Comment: no one has answered this question, so I'll accept your answer as the best that's out there. Thanks for making such an awesome implemenation of scheme for the rest of us, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have started rewriting a new plugin.

You can see the github repo for more details:

https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme.VisualStudio2

There is also a download available to try out :)